# Is there a way to manage (create/edit/verify) Wit AI Stories via their HTTP API?

Tags: wit.ai

The [Wit AI project](http://wit.ai)  added a new concept called Story to their Converse functionality. Is there a way to manage (create/edit/verify) these Wit AI Stories via their HTTP API?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Wit.ai team said when asked about having an API for stories:

"Not yet, unfortunately. The only workaround is to use the export/import and update the JSON files but I agree this is not great. Or to try to emulate the calls made by Console...very hacky sorry."

You can try API.ai, their API is more complete and it's free as well.